# PDO Fetchall, fetch, while and foreach loop only selects 1 row

Tags: php

i have a table like this

```
id  name           cat_slug
(1, 'Electronics', 'Cellphones and Accessories'),
(2, 'Electronics', 'Computers and Accessories'),
(3, 'Electronics', 'House Appliances'),
(4, 'Electronics', 'Miscellaneous'),
(5, 'Furniture', 'Office Furniture'),
(6, 'Furniture', 'House Furniture'),
(18, 'Clothing and Handbags', 'Handbags, Wallets and Purses');
```

and my php code is like this

```
$acces = 'Electronics';
                
$conn = $pdo->open();
try{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `cat_slug`FROM mall_category WHERE name = :acces");
    $stmt->execute(['acces' => $acces]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $categ = $row['cat_slug']; 
    }                 
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}
    
$pdo->close();
```

I created a dropdown menu

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Electronics</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href='shopping.php?category=<?php echo $row['cat_slug']?>'><?php echo $categ; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and want all electronics  as list in dropdown. If i use foreach loop, whileloop, or fetchAll i get only 1 row
I tried searching the entire web, stackoverflow and couldn't find a working solution. please help

Comment: Where is your loop?

Comment: Do you really want to put `cat_slug` in the URL, not `id`?

Comment: @Barmar this code is after i tried without a loop to see if it works

Comment: Show your attempt with the loops, since that's what is actually having the issue.

Comment: It should be obvious that you need a loop, how else can you do something multiple times?

Comment: @Barmar cat_slug should be in the url

Comment: Why are you selecting the id if you don't need it?

Comment: @Barmar  try{
                  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `cat_slug`FROM mall_category WHERE name = :acces");
                 $stmt->execute(['acces' => $acces]);
                 $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                $categ = $row['cat_slug']; 
                }                 
                }
                catch(PDOException $e){
                  echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
                $pdo->close();

Comment: Put it in the question. Indent it properly and put it in a code block so it's readable. See how I did that when I edited your original question.

Comment: I have edited  the code above using foreach loop

Comment: You're not creating the dropdown element in the loop.

Comment: `$categ = $row['cat_slug'];` inside the loop will of course overwrite the `$categ` variable each time round the loop. So you will see only the last occurance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the dropdown choices in the loop.

```
<?php
$acces = 'Electronics';
                
$conn = $pdo->open();
try{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `cat_slug`FROM mall_category WHERE name = :acces");
    $stmt->execute(['acces' => $acces]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$pdo->close();

?>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Electronics</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
      <li><a href='shopping.php?category=<?php echo $row['cat_slug']?>'><?php echo $categ; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>

</li>
```

Comment: sorry i didnt put the close message in my question but i have it

Comment: Thanks let me try and see if this works

Comment: @RiggsFolly I realized afterward that `$pdo` is not the same as `$conn`.

Comment: Thanks @Bamar this worked like a charm!!!